# Django model, concentrate two fields in a model and automatically generate a third field in the model

Tags: django-models

I would like to create a field maxqcertgrade that is concentration of certificate and certgrade.
Ideally, I want this field to be added automatically added for all combinations of certificate and certgrade when admin adds the certificate and certgrades.
Finally, I want to use the combine filed, maxqcertgrade in another model as Foreign Key.

The code below gives an error in my admin:
column staticpages_certgrades.maxqcertgrade does not exist

````
class Certgrades(models.Model):
    certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate, to_field='certificate', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    certgrade = models.CharField (max_length=50, unique=True, default='One')
    
    maxqcertgrade = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default='One')
    
    def save(self, *args , **kwargs):
        self.maxqcertgrade = str(self.certificate) + '.' + str(self.certgrade)
        super().save(*args , **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.maxqcertgrade
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "5. Certificate Grades"```


I have tried @property but this does not create a field that is usable...
````

Comment: Hello just to add that above code worked just fine when I completely reset the database, using a fresh one. For some reason migration was not generating the field maxqcertgrade.